# Store function inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, function

Can I do something like this?

```
$arrayFn[1] = function fnName(){
    echo "test";
}
$arrayFn[1];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) cannot have a name:

```
$arrayFn[1] = function (){
   echo "test";
};
$arrayFn[1](); // run it!
```

Comment: I believe you'd need `()` after the variable function to call it.

Comment: You are completely right, thanks. I edited the answer.

Comment: storing many function in array can cause overflow or anything bad in any chance?

Comment: @obeyjoseph: No, my Validator class normally holds 30-40 validation functions in an associative array. Nothing bad seems to happen. Although, you should do your own benchmarking to your own applications.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrayFn[1] = function (){
echo "test";
}; 
$arrayFn[1]();
```